# Fail to Create a Free iOS Development Provisioning Profile in Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

I have installed the latest Xcode (Version 7.3.1) and want to develop/debug program on real iOS device. I create a new 'HelloWorld' program and get this following error when run in iphone

```
Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found.Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found.
```

After some googling, I need to create certificate. I tried two approaches.

1. add appleID in Xcode->Preferences->Accounts.

   It shows:

   [the image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62J0f.png)

   It always shows 'Loading...'. And the Button 'View details' is locked. I have no idea.
2. Request certification from certification authority using Keychain Access

   I have create a request and save in Disk. And then I login APple Developer Center and Apple Development Agreement pop out when 'Acounts' card is clicked. 
   I agree and click 'Submit'.I get this error:

   [the image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvob5.png)

I tried any times. And also tried both in chrome and safari. It has no effect. I have no idea. Any suggestion will be much appreciated!

Comment: Try this it may helps you,
Select Team as "None"
and in Build Setting select provisioning profile as "Automatic"
and code signing identity as iOS Developer

Comment: I have tried this setup. It has no effect. I think the reason is that I don't have a valid Code Signing Identify  named iOS Developer. I try to create one. But I can not submit any information on Apple Develop website.